# Can I specify that a particular tag always have a particular class?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use CSS to specify that a particular HTML tag should always have a particular class? Something like:

```
p {
  class: fun;
}

h3 {
  class: fun;
}

.fun {
  font-family: "Comic Sans"
}
```

(I realize that this is probably never a good idea, I'm wondering for mostly academic reasons)

I'd like to achieve this without javascript/jquery -- only use CSS and HTML.

**update**

I know how to put the style specifications in each element -- what I want is to be able to change the class in one place in the .css file and have it apply to all the other elements which have the class, without having to change any HTML. i want the classes applied to all of a particular tag by default, **from the css file**. (again, I realize this isn't good design -- I'm just curious if it's possible).

Comment: It is impossible to add the classes to the elements with CSS alone, but if you want to add the set of properties inside a class to other selectors you can use a pre-processor such as less or scss. See [Less](http://lesscss.org/)'s mixins and a quick [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ehisov/2/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible with CSS or any CSS pre-processor.

You would need some HTML pre-processor (like XSLT) to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this code should work :

```
p, h3, .fun { font-family: "Comic Sans"; }
```

But if your case is 'different case' and the code above not the answer you were looking for, you may use [Less](http://lesscss.org) for solution.

Try to write some css function for this case, like below :

```
.fun{
    font-family: "Comic Sans";
}

p{ .fun(); }
h3{ .fun(); }
```

With **Less**, you are be able to create the function. Hopefully useful.

Comment: Yeah the first solution is a nice CSS-only and simple solution. Less can be used for a bit more complex stuff, those are pretty powerful when using parameters. Or use scss extending an abstract class, that way wouldn't repeat the same rule for 2 different selectors as the compiled Less css would.

Comment: interesting -- i am in an environment that can use SASS, so i'll explore that. questions: 1. the example you gave, is that a complete Less example? each class sort of gets an automatic function? 2. if so,  do you know the equivalent for SASS?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Perfect. With Less, css is so interesting with the function with own parameter which we created. Would useful and feel dynamically.

Comment: @JohnBachir 1. No, that's just a little concept and technique from **Less** strength. You can see and use more simplicity(like creating variable, mixins, nested selector, calculation, etc) what Less present on official web -> http://lesscss.org
2. As far I know, LESS and SASS has equation concept, technique and simplicity. The difference is only in the writing of syntax. You can see more info at this site -> https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/674726, http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/09/an-introduction-to-less-and-comparison-to-sass/

Comment: @JohnBachir Oh sorry, only got the notification now with Aldi's `@`me. And yes, Aldi explained it very well above, I'll just add that while simplicity is a strong Less aspect, Sass tends to be more verbose, which some argue to provide more maintainability. Though IMO that's not the most important point. Less has a couple drawbacks, such as the lack of logic (you can do some arguments overloading and `when`, but there are no `if` conditions or `for` loops) and you can't use variables as property names, so Less has much less logic than Sass. I'd say to choose based on how much logic you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve same effect like this:

```
p, h3, .fun {
  font-family: "Comic Sans"
}
```

> I'd like to achieve this without javascript/jquery -- only use CSS and HTML

You can't set classes using CSS. And you can do it using HTML, but you can't automatize it, and I guess that you don't want to add the class manually to each `<p>` or `<h3>`.

Answer (score 1):

Like so using standard CSS

```
p, h3 {
  font-family: "Comic Sans"
}
```

Else you can use something like LESS and its mixin feature: http://lesscss.org/#-mixins

Comment: Okay then you need LESS to compile the CSS for you. See my link above

Answer (score 0):

You cant set classes in CSS you would need JavaScript for that.

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName("h3")

for ( I=0; I<h.length; I++) {
    h[I].classList.add("fun")
}
```

Or you could write your HTML like:

```
<fun>This is fun!</fun>
```

And target it in CSS like this:

```
fun{ 
    font-family:Hectiva;
}
```